# Adding data from external api to db in asp.net core webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get the data from an api source and seed the data it to my database using efCore.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Get the games from the rawg api and parse them into the game domain entity
        /// </summary>
        public static async Task<List<Game>> ApiRawgGamesRequest()
        {
            var gamesList = new List<Game>();
            for (int i = 1; i < 250; i++)
            {
                using (var msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri($"https://api.rawg.io/api/games?page_size=40&page=1")))
                using (var response = await _client.SendAsync(msg))
                {
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    var gamesResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<GameResponse>();
                    gamesList.AddRange(gamesResponse.Results);
                }
            }
            return gamesList;
        }
```

then this is the code to seed the data into my database using ef core

```
/// <summary>
        /// Add the games gotten from the api into the games table in the db
        /// </summary>
        public static async Task SeedGamesData(DataContext context)
        { 
            var responseFromRawg = await ApiRawgGamesRequest();
                await context.Games.AddRangeAsync(responseFromRawg);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

And i also wrote some code to migrate the database and seed as soon as the api starts up

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // migrating the database on start
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
            using (var service = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = service.ServiceProvider;
                try
                {
                    var context = services.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
                    context.Database.Migrate();
                    SeedGames.SeedGamesData(context);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                    logger.LogError(e, "There was an error during migration");
                }
            }
            host.Run();
        }
```

But then i dont get anything or any confirmation that the code has been carried out or that i got an error. I get no errors, no warnings, nothing!. and the data still doesnt show up in my database.
is there a better way to go about adding data from an external api into your database?

Comment: What have You tried so far? Did You try to add const Game on the top level instead of pooling data from API? Or insinde `SeedGamesData` to determinate where the problem is? Exlude the API first, try some dry runs with dummy data. Also I think Your intention wasn't to add same 40 games, 250 times (see query params). For what I can tell the code itself looks like it should work. I would start debugging by getting rid of `ApiRawgGamesRequest()`.

Comment: i have tried making a mediatr controller and send he game data as a post request, that did not work, i have tried the top level adding games to the db, that didint work either.

Comment: when i try the top level method i do get an error, it just throws the exception with the error message not the actual exception

Comment: For the external api data, how many records are you trying to seed? 100? 1,000? 1 million?